StateHasChanged not updating UI
I know this is a common problem, but none of the solutions resolved my issue. All explanations seemed logical at first but after implementing them it did absolutely nothing and I'm kinda at a loss here.
Nothing I do to lets me update my UI component and just display some error messages which come from data annotation attributes. I am manually checking my data model for validity and in the case of being invalid I'm updating a list of error messages which in turn should be displayed inside my UI.
This is my component:
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Popups
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Calendars
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Inputs
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.SplitButtons
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Data
@using Blazored.Toast.Services
@using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
@using System.Text
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Spinner
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<SfGrid ID="Grid" Query="@query" HtmlAttributes="htmlAttributes" DataSource="@transactions" @ref="Grid" AllowPaging="true" AllowFiltering="true" AllowExcelExport="true"
        AllowSorting="true" Toolbar="@(new List<string>() {"Edit", "ExcelExport" })">
    <GridFilterSettings Type="Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.FilterType.FilterBar"></GridFilterSettings>
    <GridPageSettings PageCount="5" PageSize="20" PageSizes="@(new string[] { "5", "10", "20", "40", "50", "All" })"></GridPageSettings>
    <GridSelectionSettings Type="Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.SelectionType.Multiple"></GridSelectionSettings>
    <GridEvents OnActionBegin="ActionBeginHandler" OnToolbarClick="ToolbarClick" TValue="unknownasgdata"></GridEvents>
    <GridEditSettings AllowAdding="true" AllowEditing="true" AllowDeleting="true" Mode="EditMode.Dialog"  Dialog="DialogParams" ShowConfirmDialog="true">
        <Validator>
            <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
        </Validator>
        <Template>
            @{
                var unknownItem = (context as unknownasgdata);
                <div>
                    @if (validationResults.Any())
                    {
                        <div class="validation-summary">
                            @foreach (var validationResult in validationResults)
                            {
                                <div>@validationResult.ErrorMessage</div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    }
                    <br/>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label><b>Bezeichnung</b></label><br />
                        @(unknownItem.description)
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label><b>Betriebsstätte</b></label><br />
                            @(unknownItem.house)
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label><b>Leistungsnummer</b></label><br />
                            @(unknownItem.leinr)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label><b>Preis</b></label><br />
                            <SfNumericTextBox @bind-Value="@(unknownItem.articleprice)" ></SfNumericTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label><b>Mahlzeitart</b></label><br/>
                        <SfDropDownList TValue="string" TItem="string" DataSource="@(new List<string> { "Frühstück", "Mittagessen", "Abendessen" })" @bind-Value="@(unknownItem.selectedMahlzeit)"></SfDropDownList>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </Template>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <SfButton OnClick="@SubmitForm" IsPrimary="true">Speichern</SfButton>
            <SfButton OnClick="Cancel">Abbrechen</SfButton>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </GridEditSettings>
    <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(unknownasgdata.description) HeaderText="Beschreibung"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(unknownasgdata.leinr) HeaderText="Lst.Nummer" Width="150"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(unknownasgdata.house) HeaderText="Betriebsstätte" Width="100"></GridColumn>
    </GridColumns>
</SfGrid>

@code{

    private async Task<bool> ValidateModel()
    {
        validationResults.Clear();
        bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(unknownItem, validationContext, validationResults, true);
        Task.Delay(3000);
        return isValid;
    }

    private async Task SubmitForm()
    {
        if (await ValidateModel())
        {
            // Proceed with database updates
            // Your database update logic here

        }
        else
        {
            // Handle validation failures
            // Show validation messages
            validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>(validationResults);
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            await InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                StateHasChanged(); // Ensure the UI is updated to reflect validation errors
            });
            await Task.Yield();
        }
    }

}


There is, of course, a bit of code missing here and there that is important to the class but you can just assume that the basics like initializing variables are working. What I am trying to do is just Submitting my Form and doing a Validation beforehand. ValidateModel() populates the List validationResults which I want to display in my razor component. In theory, shouldn't the component re render as soon as I update the List, since I am checking for elements inside my razor components? I tried calling StateHasChanged multiple times sync and async and using Task.Delay whenever I can but nothing works and nothing lets me update the UI.

It's not clear where GridEditSettings  comes from. Tag your main libraries.

"There is, of course, a bit of code missing here and there that is important to the class but you can just assume that the basics like initializing variables are working".  You shouldn't make any assumptions when your code isn't working.  Initial question: Is SubmitForm hit when you do your submit?

I edited my post in such a way that you can see the libraries and the full component. @Mrc aka Shaun Curtis yes SubmitForm is 100% hit since I tested using debugger. StateHasChanged gets hit multiple times in various ways and the component does not get rerendered because otherwise the validationResults elements should be drawn.

Ok, this is all within a SyncFusion grid:  I'm not familiar with the SyncFusion controls so I'm bowing out.

I found out that the UI gets triggered as a hole, since I could trigger a spinner in the background using my SubmitForm. Only thing that does not "react" is the content inside the 

Add @ref="GridRef" to the SfGrid, and then call GridRef.PreventRender(false); in the places when you need to refresh the template (some onValuechange etc). This issue is caused by the Syncfusion team trying to optimize performance.(they are preventing rendering for those changes)
I have encountered the same problem right now.
